# Data Table Drop down is not working on pagination tab

Tags: css, datatable

I'm Using the data table to fetch the data from the database but the thing is my one field comes under the dropdown section, the dropdown is working on only one page, on the second pagination tab it will be showing blank anyone know the solution for that?

```
<select class="icons"> 
  <?php foreach ($country_arr as $key => $value) { 
    if ($key < 3) {?>
      <option value=""data-icon="images/country/<?php echo strtolower($value); ?>.png"class="circleno"><?php echo strtolower($value); ?> </option>
  <?php }} ?> 
</select>
```

**Page 1:**
[image: Page 1]

**Page 2:**
[image: Page 2]

Comment: On the second pagination tab, it will be showing blank even when I was check using insect element the data will showing only the select class will be removed.

Comment: how are you loading dropdown , rowcallback?

Comment: <select class="icons">
   <?php foreach ($country_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key < 3) {?><option value=""data-icon="images/country/<?php echo strtolower($value); ?>.png"class="circleno"><?php echo strtolower($value); ?>
</option>
 <?php }} ?> </select>

Comment: @ Ahmed Sunny using the above PHP Dynamic Code

Comment: no, i mean in datatable how are you displaying it. in column render function or how?